# presto + Hive Security Configuration

Tags: hive, thrift, presto, hive-metastore, starburst

we have presto cluster with Hadoop cluster
when all presto workers servers are installed on data-nodes machines

The following is example of a Hive Connector configuration file that is configured on the presto workers under catalog folder

```
connector.name=hive-hadoop2
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://metastore-node:9083
```

we want to know what are the risks , when the access from each of the presto workers isn't secured to `hive metastore` machine

as we understand presto worker/s are connect to hive meta-store by using thrift protocol and port 9083

but not clearly how presto-worker perform the authentication against the hive meta-store?

We'll appreciate to get more details about - how presto workers access to hive meta-store without hive secured and with hive secured

reference - https://docs.starburstdata.com/302-e/connector/hive-security.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hive metastore provides can be configured:

- not to use authentication (trust user identity provided by the caller)
- to use Kerberos authentication.

Both these modes are supported in Presto.

The basic mode (no auth) requires no additional configuration properties.

For the Kerberos authentication you need to set

```
hive.metastore.authentication.type=KERBEROS
hive.metastore.service.principal=...
hive.metastore.client.principal=...
hive.metastore.client.keytab=...
```

See full example & more at https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/connector/hive-security.html#example-configuration-with-kerberos-authentication

If you need further help, you can get it on `#troubleshooting` channel on [Trino (formerly Presto SQL) community slack](https://trino.io/slack.html).

Comment: regarding to "not to use authentication" can you described also - how presto worker authenticate to hive meta store , in short details the steps that are performed ( dose presto worker only read tables from hive or also write ? , )

Comment: Presto worker does not change metastore's state, it only reads it. Changes are committed all together, via the coordinator.

Comment: ok if its only read the tables , the can you described the steps how read tables performed ?